# Spring JDBC update without commit

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

I have a simple table "employee" defined as:

```
create table employee (id int, name varchar2(40));
```

I want to write an application to insert values in it and commit only after all values are inserted. Here is my code:

**Employee.java:**

```
package com.empl;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**EmployeeDAO.java:**

```
package com.empl;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public interface EmployeeDAO {
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource);

    public void create(int id, String name);
}
```

**EmployeeJDBCTemplate.java:**

```
package com.empl;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public class EmployeeJDBCTemplate {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void create(int id, String name) {
        String SQL = "insert into employee (id, name) values (?, ?)";
        jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, id, name);
    }
}
```

**MainApp.java:**

```
package com.empl;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;


public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        ApplicationContext context = new 
             ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");

        EmployeeJDBCTemplate employeeJDBCTemplate = 
            (EmployeeJDBCTemplate) context.getBean("employeeJDBCTemplate");

        employeeJDBCTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().
            setAutoCommit(false);

        employeeJDBCTemplate.create(1, "E1");
        employeeJDBCTemplate.create(2, "E2");
    }
}
```

**Beans.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd ">

   <bean id = "dataSource" class = 
        "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name = "driverClassName" value = 
            "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name = "url" value = 
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"></property>
        <property name = "username" value = "sys as sysdba"></property>
        <property name = "password" value = "pass"></property>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "employeeJDBCTemplate" class = 
        "com.empl.EmployeeJDBCTemplate">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSource"></property>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

I executed the code but when I enter SQLPlus and type the `rollback;` command, the records are still in the table.

I saw related questions but nothing seems to work.

Comment: of course they will be there. You cannot rollback a transaction from another transaction. Also setting the auto commit to false, the way you are doing it, will result in nothing as it is a different connection then the rest of the code uses. So basically your setup is flawed.

Comment: Is there a way I can find the connection used for the rest of the code? I heard about DataSourceUtils.getConnection().

Comment: Regardless you cannot rollback something from another transaction.